# How to print output without using a list

Tags: python

How do I print integers in the order in which they are inputted?

The first input x should be the number of y integers that it will accept as input and later print all y that is greater than 0 but less than 50, in the same order.

For example:

```
input:
4
5
8
52
10

output:
5
8
10
```

I used a list for this as seen below. Is there a simpler way?

```
x = int(input())
lst = []

while len(lst) <= x-1:
    i = int(input())
    i = lst.append(i)

for y in lst:
    if 0 < y < 50:
        print(y)
```

Comment: The simpler way would be to use a for-loop. But why do you not what to use a list?

Answer (score 2):

Your code could be narrowed down to:

```
lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
print(*[x for x in lst if 0 < x < 50], sep='\n')
```

Also there is no point of assigning the value of `append` (`None`) to a variable.

Or:

```
lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
for x in lst:
    if 0 < x < 50:
        print(x)
```

Comment: @PCM yes, it does. It uses one list that the OP already used, `lst`, that is appended to in the while-loop, and another list, the one created by the list comprehension  `[x for x in lst if 0 < x < 50]`

Comment: or better yet: `lst = [int(input()) for i in range(x)]` (skipping the while loop)

Comment: @PCM in my opinion, it isn't simpler. It has about the same complexity except it uses a pointless additional list

Comment: It can be more simple, if you could use a simple for loop instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: Or ```lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]``` instead of ```x = int(input())``` looks better too on top of the other line.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see which does not make much sense is this:

```
while len(lst) <= x-1:
    i = int(input())
    i = lst.append(i) #What the point of making i the result of append?
```

You can do it straight away `lst.append(i)`.

Or even `lst.append(int(input()))`.

And also you can simply do `while len(lst) < x`, there is not need for `<= x - 1`.

Rest of the code is perfect to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and a for loop -

```
x = int(input())
lst = [int(input()) for i in range(x)]

for y in lst:
    if 0 < y < 50:
        print(y)
```